# Mongodb: how to make task queue system and find/update_many in 1 query?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

- python: 3.9.17
- pymongo: 4.5.0
- OS: Ubuntu 20.04
- server (one of): Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2695 v4 @ 2.10GHz 72 cores

I am creating an app where users send tasks on high load (around 300 tasks per second) by API, servers execute it and save task result. I decided to take mongodb, so I need to get bunch of tasks that are waiting to be executed like in queue, mark them `executed=1`, then execute, then save results back. **Important in my architecture in each loop to take 1000 tasks at once (for GPU).**

1. I get first 1000 tasks from mongodb that are waiting to be executed (`executed`=0) and use many servers, because 1000 tasks must be executed within some seconds and speed is important. I need firstly grab the data and mark them `executed=1` not to allow other servers execute twice.

```py
tasks = mongo_task.find({'executed': 0}).sort('datetime', 1).limit(1000)
ids = []
for row in tasks:
    ids.append(row['_id'])
mongo_task.update_many({"_id": {"$in": ids}}, {"$set": {'executed': 1}}, upsert=False)
```

Is it the most correct way? I suppose `$in` operator can execute long time, maybe I can use range somehow? If I had `id` auto increment integer, I could make range from first and last `id`, but I read it's hard to create auto increment `id` in mongo.

2. Is it possible to wrap 1) into 1 query? If I do 2 queries like above, there can be delay where another servers will take the same tasks, so it will be duplicates execution.
   SQL equivalent:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT id, datetime, body
    FROM task
    WHERE executed=0
    ORDER BY datetime ASC
    LIMIT 1000
)
UPDATE task t
SET executed=1
FROM cte
WHERE cte.id = t.id
RETURNING id, datetime, body
```

3. By `multiprocessing` I parallel tasks execution, should I collect all results and save it in 1 query as bulk update, or saving one by one update is enough (so it will be 1000 updates instead 1 bulk)? The speed execution is important.